# Uses of “to scathe”

Tags: british-english, archaicisms

Would “We took down the foreyard and commenced to scathe it” make sense to a sailor?

Comment: Synonyms for scathe: abuse, damage, deface, despoil,detriment, harm, hurt, impair, injure, mar, misuse, mischief, misfortune.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for understanding of a nautical professional, not an English speaker.

Answer (score 0):

To Scathe means to injure, typically to cut. Your fragment wouldn't make much sense unless there was a broader context indicating the necessity of or reasoning for the action.

Comment: You could scathe a sparring partner.

Comment: Indeed you could, but I doubt what amounts to a wooden pole of indeterminate thickness would make for much of one!